# How to print stuff in a py.test finalizer

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm testing a function that writes to a logfile  (it doesn't matter that it writes to a logfile specifically, it could be doing anything, it's just what gave rise to this question)

Something like this:

```
def do_stuff():
    with open('/tmp/mylogs.txt', 'a') as f:
        f.write(str(time.time()))
        f.write(' stuff done! \n')
    return 42
```

And I can test it a bit like this:

```
def test_doing_stuff(watch_logs):
    assert do_stuff() == 42
    assert do_stuff() == 43
```

For debugging purposes, when a test fails, I want to be able to print out the new contens of the logs -- I can make a fixture a bit like this:

```
@pytest.fixture()
def watch_logs(request):
    with open('/tmp/mylogs.txt') as f:
        log_before = f.read()

    def get_new_logs():
        with open('/tmp/mylogs.txt') as f:
            log_after = f.read()
            return log_after.replace(log_before, '')

    return get_new_logs
```

Great - now I can check the log contents at any point in my tests:

```
def test_doing_stuff(watch_logs):
    assert do_stuff() == 42
    print(watch_logs())
    assert do_stuff() == 43
    print(watch_logs())
```

Hm - ah, but that second print isn't going to work, it's after the test failure.

What if my test fixture just always printed the logs out at the end of the test?  Then pytest's stdout capture would show it to me when it fails, but not when it passes!

```
@pytest.fixture()
def watch_logs(request):
    with open('/tmp/mylogs.txt') as f:
        log_before = f.read()

    def get_new_logs():
        with open('/tmp/mylogs.txt') as f:
            log_after = f.read()
            return log_after.replace(log_before, '')

    def print_new_logs():
        print('~' * 20 + ' logs ' + '~' * 20)
        print(get_new_logs())
        print('~' * 50)
    request.addfinalizer(print_new_logs)

    return get_new_logs
```

Oh, but that doesn't work because pytests's log capture isn't happening during test finalizers.

So the question is:  how can I make a test finalizer that can print stuff?

Here's an ultra-minimal gist without the (irrelevant) writing-to-a-logfile stuff:  https://gist.github.com/hjwp/5154ec40a476a5c01ba6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to help from Holger himself (thanks @hpk42!), I've got something that works. Only slightly magic/hacky.

The solution is to use a py.test hook called `pytest_pyfunc_call`, alongside a decorator called `hookwrapper`.  They give me a way to hook in some code both before and after the test runs, but also without being affected by the stdout hijacking.

We define a new function in *conftest.py*:

```
# conftest.py

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_pyfunc_call(pyfuncitem):
    yield
    print('this happens after the test runs')
    if 'watch_logs' in pyfuncitem.funcargs:
        print(pyfuncitem.funcargs['watch_logs']())
```

And now, if pytest spots any test which uses the `watch_logs` fixture, it will print its output after the test runs.

Full example:  https://gist.github.com/hjwp/4294f0acbef5345a7d46

Comment: with pytest-2.8 these mechanisms will be better documented.

Answer (score 3):

There is no documented or clean way to achieve it but here is a hack:

```
# conftest.py

def pytest_runtest_call(item):
    if hasattr(item, "_request"):
        if hasattr(item._request, "_addoutput_on_failure"):
            item._request._addoutput_on_failure()

# test_x.py
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def print_on_fail(request):
    def add():
        print ("test failed")
    request._parent_request._addoutput_on_failure = add

def test_doing_stuff(print_on_fail):
    assert False
```

We could think about a proper `request.addcall_on_failure(callback)` API.

Making the `yield_fixture` case work requires some internal probably non-trivial refactoring.

Comment: Almost.  I'd need the code to run after the main body of the test has finished (for it to pick the relevant stuff from the logfile).  Will have a peek around the plugin api... But I think the problem is that the stdout capture stuff stops working at teardown?

Comment: the ``add`` function above _is_ called after the main body of the test function and before teardown.

Comment: yep.  If I add a `print("testing")` into the `test_doing_stuff`, I get "test failed" *followed* by "testing" in my output.

Comment: checked by adding a `time.time()` to the prints, confirm the test print happens after the `add` print.

Comment: aha! if i actually call `item.runtest()` inside a try/except, and put the `_addoutput` into a finally block, it works.