# how to print out fixture value for py.test session

Tags: pytest

I am using py.test with selenium and applitools Eyes --- those latter parts don't matter, only the py.test part does.   I am computing some session-level configuration of a test run using session-level fixtures, like so:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def branch(request,timestamp):
branch = request.config.getoption('--branch')
if not branch and not request.config.getoption('--live'):
    # auto-generate branch
    branch = "auto " + timestamp
return branch
```

I would like to print the computed value as part of the test header---or any other way to get it to true stdout.

I first tried using `capsys.disable()` in the branch function above, but I got an error message that capsys is a function-level fixture so cannot be used by a session-level fixture.  Fair enough.

Then I tried to copy the example for adding information the test report header:

```
def pytest_report_header(config,branch):
    print branch
```

But it doesn't seem that branch is available as a fixture for pytest_report_header.  I could call the branch() function directly, but that kind of defeats the purpose.

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31078622/how-to-print-stuff-in-a-py-test-finalizer) but I can't tell if it applies --- it is a bit over my head py.test-wise.

This seems like it ought to be a simple thing to do, but I'm stuck --- any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out an answer to the question I asked, but I have figured out a solution to my problem:  since I am doing selenium testing, the entire output-capturing thing is irrelevant in my case, so I can turn it off entirely.

I just discovered the `-s` flag for py.test, which does just that.